# MVC: when is a file uploaded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httppostedfile

When uploading files to a server and calling a controller method does a `HttpPostedFileBase` contain the entire file or just information such as name, path, etc?

What I want to know is if the file is uploaded to the server right away or not until calling `SaveAs(path)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the file is part of your request, it is uploaded immediatly. It is just buffered into a tempfile which the system will delete once you send the Response.

If you use SaveAs, you just transfert the file into a permanent location.

Comment: how does it know to what controller method to upload the files?

Comment: I don't see the link between controller method and file downloading.